# Download faster era5 data

Tags: precipitation, python, weatherdata

I want to download multiple files for a specific area, one file daily for an specific variable like total rainfall in one month. I'm having problems with the for loop and changing the output file name stored in a desired folder.

Expecting for example january-2022, having 31 files for total precipitation TPdata, like: TP_01_01.nc TP_01_02.nc .... TP_01_31.nc

Comment: This appears to be more of a programing/coding question that an earth science one. The data you're trying to use is earth science. Someone trying to do the same for monthly production of widgets could have the same problem as you.  This is not an earth science question. It needs to be migrated.